# How do I concatenate 2 Ploneformgen form variables to use in CC Recipient of a Mailer adapter

Tags: plone, mailer, ploneformgen

I have to form fields.  If I put either one of 
request/form/participant_1_email or
request/form/participant_2_email

into the CC Expression of a Ploneformgen Mailer Adapter, they work fine.  I want to use both at the same time.

I have looked in the Zope Book, Googled multiple sites, including this one, but can't a solution for the syntax to do this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realized I wasn't clear.  I have been adding the code in the Overrides CC Expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says *Your expression should evaluate as a sequence of strings.*
Try this:

```
python:[request.form['participant_1_email'],request.form['participant_2_email']]
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  Thanks.  I guess I will look for Python solutions in the future.  Tales solutions are hard to implement and limited.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply add a second mail adapter. Then you only fill the CC-Field of the second adapter. Works perfect for my cases (Plone 4.3.6 + PloneFormgen 1.7.17).

Comment: This solution works and I do that in some cases.  I can only check one as answered so I checked the answer below, but this is a good option as well.

Comment: @JoeBigler: Feel free to upvote the answers you considered to be helpful! :-)